# Single-digit TextField input and automatic focus advance in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, focus, textfield

I'm trying to create a simple input form that lets a user enter a four-digit clock time -- hh:mm. I want to do robust checking on the input to be sure it's a valid time, and I'd like to prevent errors early (eg, you can enter "21" as the hh portion of a 24-hour clock time, but not "26").

I don't want to use pickers for this -- I find them cumbersome for choosing one of sixty minutes.

I tried to create four text fields, one each for (clock hour digit 1), (clock hour digit 2), (clock minute digit 1) and (clock minute digit 2). Those show up in the code below as ch1, ch2, cm1 and cm2.

I added numeric input checks from a separate great thread on ensuring clean numeric input here on StackOverflow. Each time I get a good digit, I want to advance focus to the next TextField in the sequence.

I set up a hashed enum to identify the fields. They're f_ch1, f_ch2, f_cm1 and f_cm2, corresponding to the digits bound to the different input TextFields.

The validation works fine. In the "else" part of the validator, when I've got a valid digit, I try expressly to set the focus to the next field in the sequence. Focus does indeed leave the field that I'm currently in, but the next one doesn't get the keyboard focus automatically. Besides that, when running on the simulator on my macbook pro, the debugger window reports:

-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID

I know this is ugly, lots of hard-coded infrastructure. I'm glad to simplify but want first of all to really understand how something like this ought to work under SwiftUI. I'd be glad of any advice. Sample code is especially welcome; I'm a reasonably new Swift developer and am often stymied by the terseness of the Apple documentation.

Here's the full code for the entry form:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  StackOverflowExample
//
//  Created by Mike Olson on 10/8/23.
//

import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // buch of hard-coded infra to automatically advance focus through the form
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case f_ch1
        case f_ch2
        case f_cm1
        case f_cm2
    }
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    // Clock digits
    @State private var ch1 = ""
    @State private var ch2 = ""
    @State private var cm1 = ""
    @State private var cm2 = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("h", text: $ch1)
                    .focusable(true, interactions: .edit)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .f_ch1)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .onReceive(Just(ch1)) { newValue in
                        let filtered = newValue.filter { "012".contains($0) } // first digit can be 0, 1, 2
                        if filtered != newValue {
                            self.ch1 = filtered
                        } else {
                            focusedField = .f_ch2
                        }
                    }
                TextField("h", text: $ch2)
                    .focusable(true, interactions: .edit)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .f_ch2)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .onReceive(Just(ch2)) { newValue in
                        let filtered = newValue.filter { (self.ch1 == "2" ? "0123" : "0123456789").contains($0) } // if the first digit's a 2, the second can't be bigger than 3
                        if filtered != newValue {
                            self.ch2 = filtered
                        } else {
                            focusedField = .f_cm1
                        }
                    }
                Text(":")
                    .font(.title3)
                TextField("m", text: $cm1)
                    .focusable(true, interactions: .edit)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .f_cm1)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .onReceive(Just(cm1)) { newValue in
                        let filtered = newValue.filter { "012345".contains($0) } // first minute digit is 0-5
                        if filtered != newValue {
                            self.cm1 = filtered
                        }
                    }
                TextField("m", text: $cm2)
                    .focusable(true, interactions: .edit)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .f_cm2)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .onReceive(Just(cm2)) { newValue in
                        let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789".contains($0) }
                        if filtered != newValue {
                            self.cm2 = filtered
                        }
                    }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 100)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `.onChange(of: ch1) { ... }` instead of `.onReceive(Just(ch1)) { ... }`  etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hard way to do a simple thing. I'll just validate the full time string that the user enters when they're finished, just before I do anything with it.